# Como passar argumentos por referência em Python?

Tags: python, parâmetros, referência, argumento

Quando eu estudei Pascal lembro que meu professor explicou que para passar um argumento por referência era necessário colocar `var` na frente da varável, nos parâmetros da função/procedimento.

Exemplo:

```
function exemplo(var, a: real):real;
```

Em Python o que é necessário fazer para isso acontecer?

A ideia é ter uma variável definida no inicio do programa, alterar ela dentro da função, e mudar o valor dela fora da função sem usar `return`.

Comment: Se a ideia é alterar o valor de uma variável externa, use o `return` e atribua novamente à variável. Explícito é melhor que implícito no Python.

Comment: É que para chegar na função que altera esse valor precisa passar por outras 3 ou 4. Aí teria que fazer retiro em todas estas?

Comment: Possivelmente. Se quiser, pode entrar no chat que podemos discutir o código.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 5):

Python funciona igual a todas as linguagens, passa tudo por valor. O que existe de diferente é que alguns valores são acessados de forma direta e outros através de uma referência, ou seja tem objetos que já são colocados na estrutura interna do Python e tem objetos que são referenciados por um valor na estrutura interna do Python.

Se esta estrutura interna é acessada por uma referência é um detalhe de implementação e não faz diferença para você programador.

Então certos valores que tem semântica por valor não podem ser passados diretamente por referência já que a linguagem não provê sintaxe para isso. Ela oferece tipos mais complexos que são sempre por referência. Os objetos de forma geral são assim, as listas e tuplas também, então encapsule em um objeto mais complexo e está resolvido. Veja:

```
def value(x):
    x = 1
def ref(x):
    x[0] = 1
x = 0
value(x)
print(x)
x = [0]
ref(x)
print(x[0])
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0wtrSb). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hjxmvssf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Function/PassByReference.py).

Comment: É que a ideia era usar uma variável de fora da função dentro, alterar ela na função, e mudar o valor sem usar return.

Comment: Que foi o que eu te demonstrei.

Comment: So adicionando um comentário, nem todas a linguagens passam parametros por valores, por exemplo em PHP objetos são passado por referencias mas tipos primitivos não. Se não me engano Java também é eassim

Answer (score 2):

Caso você queira alterar variáveis globais com objetos **imutáveis** dentro do escopo de uma função, você deve utilizar a palavra `global` para referenciar o objeto global. Exemplo:

```
def exemplo_imutavel():
    global x
    x = 20


x = 10
exemplo()

print(x)  # 20
```

Em caso de variáveis com objetos **mutáveis** (listas, set, dicionários, etc.) a manipulação pode ser feita através de parâmetros de maneira simples e direta sem o uso da palavra reservada `global`. Exemplo:

```
def exemplo_mutavel(x):
    x[0] = 10


x = [1, 2, 3]
exemplo(x)

print(x)  # [10, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Achco que não é bem isso.

Comment: É que tenho uma variável que iniciei com o programa. Em certo ponto, dentro de uma função, eu tento alterar ela mas ela só muda dentro dessa função, e não lá fora dela. Eu gostaria que mudasse como se fosse global.

Answer (score -6):

O pessoal de python não está entendendo a pergunta. Passar por referência em Harbour por exemplo é:

```
function funcaoX(x)
    x = x + 10
    return nil

y = 5
funcaoX(y)   // Passando sem referência
print(y)     // Retorna 5

funcaoX(@y)  // Passando por referência
print(y)     // Retorna 15
```

Python é uma liguagem script, por isso não é possível fazer isso, mas deve haver no Python uma maneira de passar por referência quando não se sabe o nome da variável dentro da função e precisa que a variável passada por referência reflita a alteração da variável dentro da função. Lembrando que array (lista), tupla, dicionário e objetos já são por natureza passados por referência na maioria das linguagem.

Comment: Se desconhece a linguagem ou não domina o assunto evite responder com suposições baseado em outras linguagens pois isso só gera confusão. Em Python o modelo de passagem de argumentos chama-se [passagem por atribuição](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference) que é modelo hibrido onde tipos primitivos são passados por valor e tipos abstratos são passados por referência, não havendo sintaxe ou notação especial para gerir esse controle. O que implica que esse seu exemplo não é cabível para a linguagem em questão.

Comment: Outra coisa, o Stack Overflow [não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos um [site de perguntas e resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) e sua publicação além de não responder a pergunta feita na página e ainda lança uma dúvida *...Deve haver no Python uma maneira de passar por referência...*. Use esse espaço apenas para responder a pergunta da página. Para mais informações veja [answer] e [help].

Comment: Harbour também é uma linguagem de script. Ser de script ou não nada tem a ver com o fato de ter uma sintaxe ou implicitamente passar por referência.